# In Loopback, how to require list of pairs of strings as a remote method argument

Tags: node.js, loopback

I am new to Loopback and trying to implement a remote method, one of whose arguments should be conceptually a dictionary of string -> string. I'm thinking an array of objects where each object has a single member that must be a string. Is there any way to specify this when defining a remote method?

I have tried several things that either result in runtime errors or do not behave as expected.

{ arg: "settings", type: [{ {arg: "setting", type: "string"} }]
}],

and

{arg: "settings", type: [ { arg: "setting", type: "string" }  ]
}],

I basically want to express that my method expects a list of pairs of strings.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you give an example of the required argument?

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done through remote loopback REST connector.

All you can do is `{arg: 'settings', type: 'array',http: { source: 'query' }}`.

Then your array could be delivered through `?settings=[{"setting1":"value1"},{"setting2":"value2"}]`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you are looking for :

```
{
  arg: "settings",
  type: "object",
  http: {
    source: 'body'
  },
  default: [
    {
      string1: 'value1'
    },
    {
      string2: 'value2'
    }
  ]
}
```

Try it, it should work.